PowerShell DSC, what happens when I remove settings in the .mof file?
I have a DSC config that I wrote which sets three registry keys.  I noticed that when I compile this DSC, it generates a .mof file which has three settings blocks in it, like so:

instance of MSFT_RegistryResource as $MSFT_RegistryResource1ref
{
ResourceID = "[Registry]NoAutoPlayforNonVolume";
 Ensure = "Present";
 SourceInfo = "C:\\temp\\GPOProject\\TestCustomRegPolicy\\CreateDscConfigFromParams.ps1::13::9::Registry";
 Key = "HKLM:\\Software\\Policies\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Explorer\\";
 ValueData = {
    "1"
};
 ValueName = "NoAutoPlayforNonVolume234";
 ModuleName = "PsDesiredStateConfiguration";

ModuleVersion = "1.0";

 ConfigurationName = "RegistryConfigFromParms";

};

My question is this.  Suppose I distribute this out to my workstations to then enforce.  Is simply deleting items from the .mof file enough to not enforce these settings?
My goal is to make a Grand-Unified-DSC, a GRUD if you will, and conditionally remove or not enforce settings on the device based on a script.
Question: If I do not want to enforce all settings in the config, is removing them from the .mof file the right place to make this change?

The MOF file is what Windows reads to know what settings to apply, so yes that will do it, just don't forget to regenerate your .checksum file afterwards or your client will reject the MOF file. Also, removing the section will not remove the registry keys if they have already been applied, it just won't enforce them.
